# sample size calculation for multivariable analysis

Tags: multivariate-analysis, spss, sample-size

How can I calculate the power or the adequate size of my population in a Cox multivariable regression analysis where I'm testing the association of different independent variables with my dependent variable (0/1)?
I have 843 patients 79 events and in my final multivariable model I have 4 variables (3 are 0/1; 1 is 0,1,2,3). I'm familiar only with SPSS and MedCalc.

Comment: It sounds like you have already collected your data. Why are you conducting a power analysis now?

Answer (score 0):

SPSS Statistics currently doesn't offer anything designed to do any type of power or sample size analysis for a Cox regression model. Since the program has some general mathematical functions, distribution functions, and a matrix programming language, if you know the math you can program pretty much anything, but I assume that's not what you're looking to do.

I'm not very familiar with MedCalc, but based on a quick web search it looks like it offers power analysis (specifically calculation of required sample sizes) for logrank tests for survival analysis, but nothing for general Cox regression models. I might have missed something, but it doesn't look like it'll do what you're looking for either.